# Unzip the zip file and exclude the root directory in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any library from which I can exclude the root directory while unzipping.

For example, zip file contains
 - root directory
    - first file
    - second file
    - third file

I want to exclude the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use [unzipper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper) package.

Just extract what you are looking for:

```
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip') // Your zip file
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    const fileName = entry.path;
    const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    // file_name1, file_name1 are files which you are looking for
    if (type === 'File' && ['file_name1', 'file_name1'].indexOf(fileName) >= 0) {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path/' + fileName)); // Output folder of unzip process
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```

Comment: I need whole directory.

Comment: For example if there are 100 files how can I add the name of 100 files

Comment: Just change your condition in `if condition`

Comment: Can you explain ?